# How to enforce a one-to-one relationship

Tags: 8

I want to store data about students and the books they read. Each student can read only one book, and each book can be read by only one student.

I have created a Student content type, and a Book content type, and I have created a reference field in the Student content type to reference the Book content type, and I have made the reference field to only accept one value:

[image]

So this way when I am entering data for a student, I can only enter one book value for the student (so the constraint that a student can only read one book is enforced).

But I can still enter the same book for more than one student, for example I can enter book1 for student1 and and I can also enter book1 for student2. How can I prevent this (remember that I want each book to be read by only one student)? The way I can do that if I am creating a database is to make the book foreign key in the Student table unique, but I don't think there is a way to make a field unique in Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to use an entity reference view to enforce your restriction. In the settings for your reference type you can select Default or Views: Filter by an entity reference view

You will need to create your View first, instead of adding a Page or Block you need to add Entity Reference but this isn't available as part of the Views Wizard.

Part of the filter criteria will be to hide books which have already been assigned to a student. Hope this helps you get to your solution

Answer (score 1):

Colin Shipton's solution is perfect (however if I write my post request on my own to a book ID that's already assigned, I can still assign it). Mine is just an other way to solve things:
You can also inherit from the default EntityReference widget and just adding an extra validation to it:
When the user submits the request you can check whether the chosen book ID is already assigned to another student or not. In case the answer is TRUE you just need to throw a validation error.

Comment: That sounds really promising, but can you maybe add some code snippets for clarification? Otherwise this answer stays quite abstract, IMHO.